# Check stored procedure in shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, if-statement, stored-procedures

I want to know how to write a shell script that access oracle database and check a procedure that executed earlier if it is succeeded or returned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know about procedure that executed *earlier* (in a different session?), you can't, unless the results were persisted somehow. Oracle by itself doesn't store info about every procedure call.

If you just want to run and check the stored procedure immediately from the shell script, that's a standard pattern, use `whenever sqlerror/oserror` clause:

```
sqlplus [connection_string] <<-EOF
  whenever oserror exit failure;
  whenever sqlerror exit failure;
  exec [stored_procedure];
EOF

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Procedure failed!"
  exit 1
fi
```

->[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/WHENEVER-SQLERROR.html#GUID-66C1C12C-5E95-4440-A37B-7CCE7E33491C)

Comment: Okay, If I want to know if a shell script executed earlier, is it possible to check if it was succeeded, or also I have to check immediately

Comment: Same answer - if you want to know if something happened in the past, then you must record that it happened _when it happened_.  How to check on that later depends on how you recorded it at the time it happened.